# Pstricks flowchart does not diplays properly

Tags: pstricks

I am trying to build a flow chart using pstricks, the code is below. But when I compile it the resulting PDF does not display the flowchart, in place, it looks like if all the information is superposed in a very small box. I don't know where my error is.

```
    \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage[pdf]{pstricks}
 \usepackage{epsfig}
 \usepackage{pst-grad} % For gradients
 \usepackage{pst-plot} % For axes
 \usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\begin{document}
\begin{postscript}
%\psscalebox{1.0 1.0} % Change this value to rescale the drawing.

\begin{pspicture}(0,-7.8)(19.2,7.8)
\psframe[linecolor=black, linewidth=0.04, dimen=outer](14.8,7.8)(9.2,5.8)
\rput[bl](10.0,7.0){Input:}
\psdots[linecolor=black, dotsize=0.08](10.0,6.6)
\rput[bl](10.4,6.6){Load geo.xyz}
\psdots[linecolor=black, dotsize=0.08](10.0,6.2)
\rput[bl](10.4,6.2){Load basis-set, charge,  SM}
\psframe[linecolor=black, linewidth=0.04, dimen=outer](6.4,4.6)(0.0,2.6)
\rput[bl](0.8,3.8){Initial guess for orbitals}
\psdots[linecolor=black, dotsize=0.08](1.2,3.4)
\psdots[linecolor=black, dotsize=0.08](1.2,3.0)
\rput[bl](1.6,3.4){Core Hamiltonian (OK)}
\psline[linecolor=black, linewidth=0.04, arrowsize=0.05291666666666667cm 2.0,arrowlength=1.4,arrowinset=0.0]{->}(9.2,6.6)(3.2,6.6)(3.2,4.6)
\rput[bl](1.6,3.0){Huckel Hamiltonian (No)}
\psframe[linecolor=black, linewidth=0.04, dimen=outer](14.8,4.6)(9.2,2.6)
\rput[bl](10.0,3.8){Compute the Fock}
\rput[bl](10.0,3.4){Matrix}
\psline[linecolor=black, linewidth=0.04, arrowsize=0.05291666666666667cm 2.0,arrowlength=1.4,arrowinset=0.0]{->}(12.0,5.8)(12.0,4.6)
\psline[linecolor=black, linewidth=0.04, arrowsize=0.05291666666666667cm 2.0,arrowlength=1.4,arrowinset=0.0]{->}(6.4,3.8)(9.2,3.8)
\psframe[linecolor=black, linewidth=0.04, dimen=outer](14.8,1.4)(9.2,-3.4)
\rput[bl](9.6,0.6){Solve Eigen-system:}
\rput[bl](10.0,-0.2){RHF}
\rput[bl](10.0,-1.8){UHF}
\psline[linecolor=black, linewidth=0.04, arrowsize=0.05291666666666667cm 2.0,arrowlength=1.4,arrowinset=0.0]{->}(12.0,2.6)(12.0,1.4)
\psdiamond[linecolor=black, linewidth=0.04, dimen=outer](12.0,-6.2)(2.8,0.8)
\rput[bl](10.8,-6.2){SCF converged?}
\psline[linecolor=black, linewidth=0.04, arrowsize=0.05291666666666667cm 2.0,arrowlength=1.4,arrowinset=0.0]{->}(12.0,-3.4)(12.0,-5.4)
\psframe[linecolor=black, linewidth=0.04, dimen=outer](19.2,0.6)(15.6,-2.6)
\rput[bl](16.0,-0.2){Updates}
\psdots[linecolor=black, dotsize=0.08](16.4,-1.0)
\rput[bl](16.8,-1.0){Orbitals}
\psdots[linecolor=black, dotsize=0.08](16.4,-2.2)
\rput[bl](16.8,-2.2){Charge density}
\psline[linecolor=black, linewidth=0.04, arrowsize=0.05291666666666667cm 2.0,arrowlength=1.4,arrowinset=0.0]{->}(14.8,-6.2)(17.6,-6.2)(17.6,-2.6)
\psline[linecolor=black, linewidth=0.04, arrowsize=0.05291666666666667cm 2.0,arrowlength=1.4,arrowinset=0.0]{->}(17.6,0.6)(17.6,3.8)(14.8,3.8)
\rput[bl](16.0,-6.2){No}
\psframe[linecolor=black, linewidth=0.04, dimen=outer](6.4,-4.2)(0.0,-7.8)
\rput[bl](0.4,-5.0){Get Post-Hartree-Fock start-up:}
\psline[linecolor=black, linewidth=0.04, arrowsize=0.05291666666666667cm 2.0,arrowlength=1.4,arrowinset=0.0]{->}(9.2,-6.2)(6.4,-6.2)
\rput[bl](7.6,-6.2){Yes}
\end{pspicture}
%}
\end{postscript}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Are you compiling with LaTeX > dvips > ps2pdf or with XeLaTeX? Or are you compiling with pdfLaTeX? You should one of the former two, not pdfLaTeX, or include the `--shell-escape` option to enable direct compilation to PDF.

Comment: Compiling with pdflatex --enable-write18 (I use MiKTeX) works fine, except the resulting flowchart is too large. Also, it would be better to load `pst-node` and use its `psmatrix` environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rescale it to the linewidth of the document:

```
\begin{document}
\noindent
\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{%
\psframebox*[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=black!10,framesep=10pt]{%
\begin{pspicture}(0,-7.8)(19.2,7.8)
\psframe[linewidth=0.04, dimen=outer](14.8,7.8)(9.2,5.8)
\rput[l](10.0,7.0){\tabular{@{}ll@{}} 
  \rlap{Input:}\\
  \textbullet & Load geo.xyz\\
  \textbullet & Load basis-set, charge,  SM\endtabular}
\psframe[linewidth=0.04, dimen=outer](6.4,4.6)(0.0,2.6)
\rput[l](0.8,3.8){\tabular{@{}ll@{}} 
  \rlap{Initial guess for orbitals}\\
  \textbullet & Core Hamiltonian (OK)\\
  \textbullet & Huckel Hamiltonian (No)\endtabular}
\psline[style=aline]{->}(9.2,6.6)(3.2,6.6)(3.2,4.6)
\psframe[linewidth=0.04, dimen=outer](14.8,4.6)(9.2,2.6)
\rput[bl](10.0,3.8){Compute the Fock}
\rput[bl](10.0,3.4){Matrix}
\psline[style=aline](12.0,5.8)(12.0,4.6)
\psline[style=aline](6.4,3.8)(9.2,3.8)
\psframe[linewidth=0.04, dimen=outer](14.8,1.4)(9.2,-3.4)
\rput[bl](9.6,0.6){Solve Eigen-system:}
\rput[bl](10.0,-0.2){RHF}
\rput[bl](10.0,-1.8){UHF}
\psline[style=aline](12.0,2.6)(12.0,1.4)
\psdiamond[linewidth=0.04, dimen=outer](12.0,-6.2)(2.8,0.8)
\rput[bl](10.8,-6.2){SCF converged?}
\psline[style=aline](12.0,-3.4)(12.0,-5.4)
\psframe[linewidth=0.04, dimen=outer](19.2,0.6)(15.6,-2.6)
\rput[bl](16.0,-0.2){Updates}
\psdots[dotsize=0.08](16.4,-1.0)
\rput[bl](16.8,-1.0){Orbitals}
\psdots[dotsize=0.08](16.4,-2.2)
\rput[bl](16.8,-2.2){Charge density}
\psline[style=aline](14.8,-6.2)(17.6,-6.2)(17.6,-2.6)
\psline[style=aline](17.6,0.6)(17.6,3.8)(14.8,3.8)
\rput[bl](16.0,-6.2){No}
\psframe[linewidth=0.04, dimen=outer](6.4,-4.2)(0.0,-7.8)
\rput[bl](0.4,-5.0){Get Post-Hartree-Fock start-up:}
\psline[style=aline](9.2,-6.2)(6.4,-6.2)
\rput[bl](7.6,-6.2){Yes}
\end{pspicture}%
}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

However, PSTricks also knows `\psTextFrame` which makes live easier ...